# Is there any performance implication from using varchar(max) over varchar(n) in cast/convert?

Tags: sql-server, performance, datatypes

Consider the following expression, which truncates (**does not round**) the milliseconds from a date-time value:

```
declare @now datetime2 = sysdatetime();
select @now;
select convert(datetime2, convert(varchar(20), @now, 120));

-- Output
2021-07-30 09:38:33.5566666
2021-07-30 09:38:33.0000000
```

Notice the `varchar(20)`. I don't like that specific length value because if I should change my datatypes there could be data loss:

```
declare @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset() at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';
select @now;
select convert(datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(20), @now, 120));

-- Output
2021-07-30 02:39:12.7200000 -07:00
2021-07-30 02:39:12.0000000 +00:00 -- oops, we lost the time zone too!
```

Hence I'd much rather use the following:

```
declare @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset() at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';
select @now;
select convert(datetimeoffset, convert(varchar(max), @now, 120)); -- note MAX not N

-- Output
2021-07-30 02:41:16.4566666 -07:00
2021-07-30 02:41:16.0000000 -07:00
```

My question is, is there any sort of meaningful performance implication in using `varchar(max)` over `varchar(N)` - including but not limited to memory allocations?

I'm aware there are [implications for query performance if using `(max)` datatypes over `(N)` datatypes in predicates](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/10/max-data-types/), but in my particular examples I'm not doing that - just allocating the `varchar`s then throwing them away after converting them back to the desired datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, to answer your question:

Yes, it can affect performance, as space needs to be allocated to hold large values in the query engine.

In your case, you could also use a suitably large size such as `varchar(50)` which would easily hold whatever you needed.

**But you shouldn't be doing any of this in the first place.**

When rounding dates, you should not convert to `varchar` and back, as this has poorer performance, and issues involving culture/style.

**Instead, use standard rounding techniques:**

```
declare @now datetimeoffset = sysdatetimeoffset() at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';
declare @epoch datetimeoffset = CAST(@now AS date);
select dateadd(
    second,
    datediff(second, @epoch, @now at time zone 'utc'),
    @epoch) at time zone 'Pacific Standard Time';
```

You can use any date for `@epoch`, it's just a point to measure by. As long as you use the same value in both places it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2022 and later, you can use the [`DATETRUNC`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql) built in function:

> Starting with SQL Server 2022 (16.x), this function returns an input *date* truncated to a specified *datepart*.

```
DECLARE @now datetimeoffset = 
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() 
    AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time';

SELECT 
    Original = @now, 
    Truncated = DATETRUNC(SECOND, @now);
```

| Original | Truncated |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 02:12:01.7056958 -07:00 | 2023-04-01 02:12:01.0000000 -07:00 |

```
DECLARE @now datetime2(7) = 
    SYSDATETIME();

SELECT 
    Original = @now, 
    Truncated = DATETRUNC(SECOND, @now);
```

| Original | Truncated |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 22:12:01.7516845 | 2023-04-01 22:12:01.0000000 |